# jQuery change doesn't fire in IE from expanded select

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

http://jsfiddle.net/e3ZJa/9/

Two small tests:

1. select select (but don't expand it), press down and press enter, you will see 1 and 2 in all browsers (let me know if I'm wrong, I tested in IE and Firefox)
2. expand select, select option by pressing up and down, and press enter, you will see only 2 in IE. Why? I want to see 1 2
   what I should modify to get it work? I need to launch one function on select change and another one when user presses enter.

**UPD:**
About jQuery version we using 1.4.2 in our project, looks like we need to update it, but we will need to retest all project

Comment: works for me as it should, firing the change event. IE8

Comment: you expand select, select new value with up and down, press enter and see 1 and 2? or you see only 2?

Comment: When I tried your second test in IE8, I got 2 when I pressed enter and then got 1 when I tabbed off the control.  It seems that IE only registers it as changed after it loses focus (presumably to not spam change messages)

Comment: This is how the version you are using worked, you see the 2, if you again click the select (not selecting anything) by clicking it, you see the keyup fired.  IF you update to jQuery 1.7.1, you will see both events fire as you desire.

Comment: yes I saw it , what I should change to see 1 2 in second test?

Answer (score 1):

This is how 1.4.4 the version you are using worked, you see the 2, if you again click the select (not selecting anything) by clicking it, you see the keyup fired (the 1 in your test case).  This is fired on the focus change.

IF you update to jQuery 1.7.1, you will see both events fire as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine in IE7  by using Jquery 1.5.2 and above.